# E: Package 'cassandra' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra in Ubuntu 14.04 and i am facing this problem when i am running this command : `sudo apt-get install cassandra` .

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree 
 Reading state information... Done
 Package cassandra is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
 E: Package 'cassandra' has no installation candidate
```

Please help me to fix it. Tried some links but it didn't worked. I need to install cassandra on my machine

Comment: this may help https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html

Comment: follow this tutorial, it will get your job done : https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-ubuntu-14.04/

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you followed the steps listed here: http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ and if when you run `sudo apt-get update` you encountered this error:

`GPG error: http://www.apache.org 311x InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A278B781FE4B2BDA`

add the public key:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key A278B781FE4B2BDA`

and then again:

`sudo apt-get update`

finally:

`sudo apt-get install cassandra`

Comment: didn't worked for me :(

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/apt/sources.list, find the line that describes your source repository for Debian and add contrib non-free to the end of the line. For example: 
deb http://some.debian.mirror/debian/ $distro main contrib non-free